# Send value at php page using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, cordova-2.0.0

I have an html page for a phonegap application.
In this page i have to send this value SAT000000002574 at this php page :

```
http://sat3.altervista.org/index.php
```

I can not use php for make this work because phonegap doesn't support it. 
For this reason i have to use jquery or javascript.
In which way i can send this value??

Comment: If im understanding you correctly you want to use ajax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**$.get**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) as below:

```
$.get('http://sat3.altervista.org/index.php', {myValue: 'SAT000000002574', moreValue: 15}, function(data) {

});
```

In `php` file you can access `myValue` as below:

```
$myValue = isset($_GET['myValue']) ? $_GET['myValue'] : '';
```

Comment: And after in the php page in which way i can take the value???

Comment: Answer updated for that

Comment: Onether things....if i would  send an array of value and not only one how i can do??

Comment: Use `{}`, like `{myValue: 'SAT000000002574', moreValue: 15}`, answer updated

Comment: And after in the php how i can take the array values?

Comment: {myValue: 'SAT000000002574', myValue2: 'SAT000000002575',myValue3: 'SAT000000002575'}............is correct??

Comment: Yes, you can access them in `php` file as `$_GET['myValue']`, `$_GET['myValue2']`, `$_GET['myValue3']`